# Как реализовать кратность?

Tags: javascript, массивы, алгоритм

Подскажите, как именно можно реализовать кратность?

*Условие :*

> Даны два неубывающих массива `x` и `y`. Найти их пересечение, то есть неубывающий массив `z`, содержащий их общие элементы, причем кратность каждого элемента в массиве `z` равна минимуму его кратностей  в массивах `x` и `y`.

```
    let x = [];
    for(let i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{

x[i] = prompt("Введите элемент массива x");

 }

 function compareNumeric(a, b) 
{
  return a - b;
}

 x.sort(compareNumeric);
 alert("Массив х = " + x);

 let y = [];
for(let i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
 y[i] = prompt("Введите элемент массива y");
}
 y.sort(compareNumeric);
 alert("Массив у = " + y);


function count(s, c)
{
let sum = 0;
for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
{
    if (s[i] == c)
     sum ++
}
 return sum
}

    function Intersection(a, b) 
 {
    let z = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < b.length; i++)
    {
        if(b.includes(a[i]) && count(a, a[i]) < count(b, b[i]))
        {
             z.push(a.slice(i, i + count(a, a[i])));
        }
        else if (b.includes(a[i]) && count(b, b[i] < count(a, a[i])))
             z.push(b.slice(i, i + count(b, b[i])));
    }

     return z.sort(compareNumeric);
}

   alert ("Пересечение = " + Intersection(x, y));
```

Comment: А каким методом находите пересечение?

Comment: @MBo через includes()

Comment: Обычный однопрходный алгоритм построения пересечения двух упорядоченных массивов даст вам именно такой результат, как описано в условии.

Comment: @AnT то есть, под "минимум кратностей элемента" имеется в виду одно его вхождение в массив с пересечением?

Comment: @lora Нет, не одно. А именно как сказано в условии: минимум кратностей. Если в одном массиве два одинаковых, а в другом - три, то в пересечении должно получиться два.

Comment: @AnT да, я так изначально и мыслила. Можете, пожалуйста, подробнее рассказать об однопроходном алгоритме пересечения упорядоченных массивов?

Comment: @lora Так Вы его уже получили ;)

Comment: @AnT не совсем понимаю запись "indexA", это A.indexOf()?

Comment: @lora Вы, видимо, ко мне обращались - это просто текущий индекс в массиве, `indexOf()` вообще не нужен.

Comment: @MBo Да, теперь поняла, спасибо Вам большое :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C помощью `indexof` можно найти весь диапазон индексов одинаковых чисел.

Однако для сортированных массивов выгоднее использовать алгоритм, подобный слиянию в `MergeSort`. [Код](https://playcode.io/151311?tabs=console&script.js&output):

```
A = [2,3,3,4,5,5,5,7];
B = [1,3,3,4,4,5,5,6];
C= [];
indexA = 0;
indexB = 0;
while (indexA < A.length && indexB < B.length) {
     if (A[indexA] < B[indexB]) 
        indexA++
     else
        if (A[indexA] > B[indexB]) 
           indexB++
        else {
          C.push(A[indexA]);
          indexA++;
          indexB++;
       }
 }
 console.log(C);

 >>[ 3, 3, 4, 5, 5 ]
```

Comment: поняла, спасибо за помощь)